# Shorthand for ! -z

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Looking for alternative to:

```
local foo=""

if [[ ! -z "$foo" ]]; then
  echo "foo is actually not empty."
fi
```

is there some way to check if a variable is defined (not empty) without negation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The opposite of `-z word` is `-n word`, or simply `word` without an operator:

```
foo=x
if [[ "$foo" ]] ; then
    echo "foo is not empty"
fi
```

Note that you can't test between an empty value and an unset value that way. You'll need `${foo+x}` for that: `[[ "${foo+x}" = x ]]`  will be true for any *set* value, even an empty string.

`-z`, `-n` would work with the standard `[ .. ]` test, too, you don't need `[[ .. ]]` for those. The difference here is that within `[ .. ]` the variables need to be quoted.

Comment: thanks, I will tend to be explicit and use the `-n`

Answer (score 0):

```
var=''
var2='foo'
e () { test ${#1} -gt 0; }
e "$var" && echo true || echo false
    false
e "$var2" && echo true || echo false
    true
```